# socket.emit throwing timeout error even when message was successfully sent

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

```
  socket.on("msg-sent", (msg, hit, receiver) => {
    socket
      .to(SOCKET_ID_DIR[hit]?.[receiver])
      .emit("msg-received", msg, (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log("msg not received ", err);
        } else {
          console.log("msg received");
        }
      });
  });
```

I have 2 browsers open. When a message is sent by one browser, the socket io snippet above will emit this message to the other browser.

I know that the message is successfully emitted because the message is logged to console on the other browser. Yet, this `console.log("msg not received ", err)` is being printed out on the socket io server side.

```
msg not received  Error: operation has timed out
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/user/Documents/project/socket_22/node_modules/socket.io/dist/broadcast-operator.js:182:17)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:557:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7)
```

Why?

EDITED:

This is what happens on the client side when `msg-received`.

```
    socket.current.on("msg-received", (msg) => {
      set_re_msg(msg);
    });
```

Comment: is this the only communication that throws error. do you emit other events successfully?

Comment: You are using `emit` with `ack`. Does the other browser call the callback function when receive the "msg-received" message?

Comment: I have updated the question with what happens when the client receives the message.

Answer (score -1):

Starting with Socket.IO v4.4.0, you can now assign a timeout to each emit: [Documentation is here](https://socket.io/docs/v4/emitting-events/)

```
socket.timeout(5000).emit("my-event", (err, response) => {
  if (err) {
    // the other side did not acknowledge the event in the given delay
  } else {
    console.log(response);
  }
});
```